# Chi Square Test - Goodness of fit to test significance of incomplete system

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

A general question I'd like to ask. I have two systems, one has complete data, the other one we found only has 80% of data, the rest 20% is missing for reasons yet to be found. But for short term, I still want to work on those 80% of data for analysis, data mining or whatever. But first I want to figure out if missing 20% of data is significant or not?

I'm using the chisq.test in R, I pulled the probability distribution from the complete system which I use as my expected distribution. and use the data from the system that has 20% of missing data to run a goodness of fit test given the p.

Does the procedure make sense? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not data that's 'significant' or 'not significant'. Presumably you're after a hypothesis test of something, but it's not 100% clear what you want to test. What do you mean by 'is significant' there? What is it you want to find out?

Comment: Would it make it more clear if I say I want to test the data in the incomplete system is following the same distribution as the data expected in "perfect" system.

Comment: If you had all the data in the incomplete system, presumably you wouldn't expect it to be exactly identical to the data from the complete one, simply due to random variation. Is that right? If that's the case you should not use the complete one as the expected distribution. If the missing data is at random, you can do a chi-squared test that they both come from the same distribution. (There's still not enough detail to be entirely clear about what you actually do have. I've had to make guesses.)

Comment: No, if I had the incomplete system complete, presumably all data should match (e.x. transaction data). The reason people may want to use the incomplete system is it has way more other information than the current complete system and easy to access. What I did was actually use the complete system as expected distribution, and do a chi-squared test to figure out if the difference is significant or not.